# Template engine / tool that can template out whole directory trees

Tags: library, text-processing, templating, directories, file

#### What I'm looking for

I'm looking for a text templating engine (think e.g. Jinja2, Mako, or Liquid) or a higher-level library/tool making use of such an engine that supports templating on the level of whole directory trees instead of just on the level of text within a file.

All features available for templating within files (e.g. loops, conditions, etc.) should also be available for this filesystem-level templating. E.g. there should be a way to specify declaratively that you want it to template out multiple recipes according to some recipe template `{{ recipe_name }}.md` given a list of recipe data.

Of course this isn't that hard to do manually with existing template engines, but I run into this so often that I'd be surprised if there wasn't a ready-made system with a nice declarative syntax for it by now.

#### Similar existing software

[cookiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter) comes close in that it does template out whole directory trees and even lets you put placeholders in filenames, e.g. you can name a file in your template directory `{{ module_name }}.py` and it will insert a provided module name when rendering it to disk, but AFAIK it doesn't support templating out files from loops over lists. It's also not meant to be general-purpose and has some [odd conventions](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter/issues/380) that stem from its intended use as a project templating tool.

Answer (score 1):

I once again ended up writing my own which supports all the features I asked for in my question and then some:

- [mondir](https://smheidrich.gitlab.io/mondir/)

*After* I got done writing it, I found out that there are similar projects already on PyPI:

- [dirtempl](https://pypi.org/project/dirtempl/)
- [dirtemplate](https://pypi.org/project/dirtemplate/)

I haven't tested them though.